# WPF - "Initialize Component does not exist in the current context" caused when adding project reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am developing a WPF application which will utilise a class library project within my solution.

I began by creating the view in my Xaml file and adding the UI functionality.

I have now added a reference to my class library which sits in the same solution and I am receiving the error:

> The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

When I remove the reference the error disappears and I can compile fine.

Both project utilise the .NET framework 4.5.1 and I have another WPF application which utilises this project and references it without issue.

The only advice I find on this gives advice on ensuring a correctly named class XAML which matches with XAML.cs. I have checked this and it is fine:

```
<Window x:Class="My.GUI.DirWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DirWindow" Height="756.7" Width="961">
```

and

```
namespace My.GUI
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for DirWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class DirWindow : Window
{

    public DirWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Loaded += WindowOnLoaded;

        //Closing += WindowOnClosing;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be and why referencing/unreferencing this project reliably toggles this error...It's just a class library, but what sort of things should I be looking for in the referenced project?

Comment: Do you have an InitializeComponent() method declared for your DirWindow class?

Comment: This usually occurs when the XAML cannot be resolved. Are you getting a type name conflict that results in your XAML file becoming invalid?

Comment: I do have the method declared yes. There are no other conflicts it is simply the error I showed above which is what is so strange.I have been removing potentially conflicting references between the WPF and the class library in case that is causing some issues, but nothing yet.

Comment: Has your referenced project a class with the same name?(DirWindow) Just in case, i'd try to change DirWindow for DirWindow1 or something like  that in your .xaml and .cs files and see if that solves the problem

Comment: DirWindow is already a changed name as I thought the same, it was previously named differently. It hasn't solved the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. My class library was using log4net and my WPF project was not referencing log4net. I'm not sure exactly why this caused issue as there is no log4net functionality within my WPF application. If anyone has any idea why this issue presented itself in this was it would be nice to know.

In any event this has resolved the issue and my project now compiles fine.